# Can Wordpress Multisite share pages between each other?

Tags: wordpress, internationalization, multisite, regional-settings

I’ve got a certain use case where I want to create pages that are only for a specific language/region, but have all over pages should be available for all languages/regions. Is this possible using WordPress Multisite? Or is there a similiar plugin?

- Home en/de/fr
- About en/de/fr
- Contact en/de/fr
- Shop de